# Unable to get a Foreign key

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008

```
USE Kudler_FF
ALTER TABLE Employee_Tbl
ADD CONSTRAINT FK_Employee_Tbl
FOREIGN KEY (JobTitle) REFERENCES Job_Tbl (JobTitle);
```

Message I am getting:

> Msg 547, Level 16, State 0, Line 2
>   The ALTER TABLE statement conflicted with the FOREIGN KEY constraint "FK_Employee_Tbl". The
>   conflict occurred in database "Kudler_FF", table "dbo.Job_Tbl", column
>   'JobTitle'.

What did I add or not add

Answer (score 1):

You usually only get an error adding a foreign key constraint when the constraint would be violated by the current data.

In other words, you probably have a value in `Employee_Tbl(JobTitle)` that does not exist in `Job_Tbl(JobTitle)`.

You would not be able to add such a constraint until your data is modified so that a violation would not occur.

Find the values for `JobTitle` in `Employee_Tbl` that *don't* exist in `Job_Tbl` and then add them to that latter table.

I'm not sure of the exact syntax for SQL Server but you could start with:

```
select distinct JobTitle from Employee_Tbl
where JobTitle not in (
    select distinct JobTitle from Job_Tbl
)
```